# preg_match accept 0 characters or between 50 to 100

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to write a regex that'll accept a blank string, or, if the string isn't blank it should be between 50 to 100 characters. So the user can submit a blank field, or if he chooses to fill in data, that data should to be between 50 to 100 characters.

How do I add that to the regex below?

`preg_match('/^[a-z0-9\s]{50,100}$/i',$str)`

Comment: Why not check with an `if(!empty)` then use the regex after? I don't think you can do this with a regex alone, but I could be wrong. I'm no regex guru.

Comment: What should happen if the string is not between 50 and 250 characters? Should it not match anything?

Comment: @HaR If its < 50 or >250 return false

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try Regex: `^(?:[a-z0-9 ]{50,100})?$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yPvq4Y/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `^$` with an alternation added to your current pattern:

```
preg_match('/^$|^[a-z0-9\s]{50,100}$/i', $str)
```

I have tested this and empty string is accepted.  Otherwise, the only way to match would be for the input have 50 to 100 alphanumeric/whitespace characters.

Answer (score -1):

I would first trim() it, then apply your rule-set to the input, like remove multi (spaces|tab|etc) within the input, then validate the input, that way you end up with what you want, or return the form and let them fix their input.